# Php script triggering python script in background

Tags: python, php, exec, background-process, shell-exec

**Current Situation**

I created a php script, to start the python script.

Following is the script:

```
$python_file = "/var/www/web/test.py 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/mylog 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &";
$command = "nohup python3 ".$python_file;
exec($command);
```

**Problem:**

After triggering the php script, the script keeps on running and finally it returns 504 error page.

**Expected Solution**

After triggering the above script, it needs to return immediately after the exec statement. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

add `&` to run in the background

```bash
$python_file = "/var/www/web/test.py 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/mylog 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &";
$command = "nohup python3 ".$python_file . " &";
exec($command);
```

Comment: Actually, I added & at the end of $python_file variable. one more & is necessary?